# How do I pass variable(s) from a VB.NET application to an already running Java application on the same computer?

Tags: java, vb.net, variables, send

I hope this doesn't sound silly.  I've looked it up but can't find anything.

Let's use this example to keep from being too general.  In my VB.NET application, I want to do this:

```
Dim ASDF As String = "This is a string."
Dim UIOP As Integer = 54
```

From here, I want to send the values of these variables to a Java application that is already running locally on my computer - I don't want the program to start the application because it is already running.  What would be the simplest way to achieve this?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would you consider using some sort of database, or even a file?

Comment: Well, would that make it simpler in any way?  I only have to pass one or two variables to the Java program, so it seemed kind of redundant to me.

Comment: Is the java program expecting the data?  How will the java program know that the data is available?  Is the java program written in such a way that it can receive the data?  Can you alter the java program?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once which involved passing information from a Python program to a C++ application which was already running, same as in your case. 
The most reliable solution I could find was to simply have the first program create a text file with the relevant info, and then have the second program read and destroy the file. This solution works really well if you only have to pass information between programs a few times, not continuously.

A more structured way of doing the same thing, instead of using a text file, would be to use an XML file. Both Java and VB.NET support XML data parsing, VB.NET with XmlTextReader and Java with Document Object Model. Using xml will allow you to have a hierarchical structure for your data.